# what's the quickest way to simple-merge files and what's the quickest way to split an array?

Tags: python

what's the quickest way to take a list of files and a name of an output file and merge them into a single file while removing duplicate lines?
something like

cat file1 file2 file3 | sort -u > out.file

in python.

prefer not to use system calls.

AND:

what's the quickest way to split a list in python into X chunks (list of lists) as equal as possible? (given a list and X.)

Comment: the chunks should maintain the order in the original list. equal here refers to size. so LIST = (x1,x2,x3,x4) is split into ((x1,x2),(x3,x4)) for X=2.

Comment: By quickest, do you mean quickest to write or quickest to execute? Also, do you want to preserve line order?

Comment: You should split this question in two - the things you're asking are not related to each other and need to be separated.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
lines = set()
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as inF:
        lines.update(inF)
with open(outfile, 'w') as outF:
    outF.write(''.join(lines))
```

Second:

```
def chunk(bigList, x):
    chunklen = len(bigList) / x
    for i in xrange(0, len(bigList), chunklen):
        yield bigList[i:i+chunklen]

listOfLists = list(chunk(bigList, x))
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first:

```
lines = []
for filename in filenames:
    f = open(filename)
    lines.extend(f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
lines = list(set(lines)) #remove duplicates
f = open(outfile_name, 'w')
f.write(''.join(lines))
```

assuming that the files are a reasonable length as all the data from the files will be stored in memory simultaneously. If you want to preserve the side effect of `sort` ordering the lines, then just add `lines.sort()` before the file is written.

And the second:

```
step_size = len(orig_list)/num_chunks
split_list = [orig_list[i:i+step_size] for i in range(0, len(orig_list), step_size)]
```